# Unable to understand inequality trigonometry graph $\sin x > \dfrac{-1}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, graphing-functions

I am unable to understand the graph plotting of $\sin (x) > \dfrac{-1}{2}$ on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/414o57rlov) I have plotted
Here is the [image]

I think the graph should be the shaded region between like [image: this]

Note second one is not the actual graph of previous function. I don't know to plot the above graphically so I have use an example. I hope I clear my point. 
Can anyone explain how it being plotted on Desmos? Or is this correct ? If yes how?

Comment: It is shading the $x$ points without regard for the $y$ points.

Comment: plot graph $y=\sin x$ then draw the line $y=-0.5$. Now look where graph of $\sin x$ is above the line $y=-0.5$

Comment: This is because you have no condition on $y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desmos is interpretting you request as find all $(x,y)$ such that $x$ satisfies $\sin(x) \ge -\frac12$. Hene for every $x$ that satisfies that condition, every $y$ is included. Hence we get all the vertical stripes.

Probably, you want to plot the following:

[image]

Comment: @[Siong Thye Goh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/306553/siong-thye-goh) so desmos plotting is correct? I mean the graph you have plotted is different in theory as well? I expected my graph like yours.

Comment: desmos is doing what what the user is telling it to do regardless of whether that is the user's intention. It is told to shade all $(x,y)$ as long as $x$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: I got it, it just a programmed. But sorry I am not able to make my question clear. Is the graph you plotted above is for $sin(x) > \dfrace{-1}{2} or it is a different function. I am not getting desmos involved into this. Or I am what I assumed is incorrect

Comment: what is the original problem that you want to solve? should there be a variable $y$ in the first place? I am shading $\{ (x,y)|  - \frac12 \le y \le \sin(x)\}$ while you plotted $\{ (x,y)|  - \frac12  \le \sin(x)\}$

Comment: Original problem is simply plotting the inequality $sin(x) > \dfrac{-1}{2}$
I have solved it on paper and found out the range which is $(2n\pi - \dfrac{\pi}{6} , 2n\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6})$ $n\in I$

Comment: I can't figure out what is the question asker is thinking... but my personal view is the plot in my answer could be more interpretable? where we we draw $y=\sin(x)$ as the upper bound and $y=-\frac12$ as the lower bound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76781/discussion-between-brij-raj-kishore-and-siong-thye-goh).